# create-react-app how to use directly imported scripts in html

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, create-react-app

I am using bootstrap in my react app generated with create-react-app

Below are two imports that I am using in my index.html

```
<script src="./vendor/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

However in code when I use something like

```
$('.dropdown').dropdown()
```

I get an error as - **error  '$' is not defined  no-undef**
Can someone help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need jQuery, run:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

Then you can use it in the app code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Note that this only works with versions 2.x and above.

---

You can also use it as a script tag.
**This is not encouraged.**

To do it, put jQuery into the `public` folder and add this to HTML:

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use it from the app:

```
const $ = window.$;
```

---

In general I would recommend trying [React Bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) instead of Bootstrap in React projects. It provides similar looking components but doesn't need jQuery and works on top of React.

I hope this helps! Please file issues if you're confused about something. We are happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to require the jquery package. Include `var $ = require ('jquery')` (after installing it -- npm install --save jquery) on all the components that reference jQuery.